# mongodb: push to subarray of array element or add to array if not existing

Tags: mongodb

Consider a collection `webs` with documents of the following structure

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5631e7f6cc6b441000ad9033"),
    "name": "web1",
    "pagehits": [
      {
        "ip": "12.34.56.78",
        "hits": [
          ISODate("2015-10-28T11:06:37.536+0000"),
          ISODate("2015-11-28T11:06:37.536+0000")
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

A web has (of course) an `_id`, a `name`, (other not mentioned properties) and a `pagehits` array. Each array item corresponds to a single ip. Additionally each page hit is saved as a date in the `hits` subarray of the `pagehit` item.

A pseudo-algorithm of the `add pagehit` function would therefore look like

- `find` web with provided `ObjectId`
- is there already an array item with the current users ip?

  - **yes**: append current date to already existing `pagehits` array element
  - **no**:  append a new item to the `pagehits` array, with ip being the current users ip, and `hits` being an array containing only the current date.

Is it possible to realize this `insert hit` function with a single MongoDB call (`findOneAndUpdate`)?

All webs are guaranteed to exist, so there is no need to upsert a whole document in the collection.

Examples for the two cases that might happen:

**Case 1)** Hit with IP *192.168.0.1* (not yet in list): A new subdocument is added

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5631e7f6cc6b441000ad9033"),
    "name": "web1",
    "pagehits": [
      {
        "ip": "12.34.56.78",
        "hits": [
          ISODate("2015-10-28T11:06:37.536+0000"),
          ISODate("2015-11-28T11:06:37.536+0000")
        ]
      },
      {
        "ip": "192.168.0.1",
        "hits": [
          ISODate("2016-04-08T11:25:37.536+0000")
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Case 2)** Hit with IP *12.34.56.78* (already in list): The current date is pushed to the *hits* array

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5631e7f6cc6b441000ad9033"),
    "name": "web1",
    "pagehits": [
      {
        "ip": "12.34.56.78",
        "hits": [
          ISODate("2015-10-28T11:06:37.536+0000"),
          ISODate("2015-11-28T11:06:37.536+0000"),
          ISODate("2016-04-08T11:25:37.536+0000")
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera it's not a duplicate for the post you linked. I assert the  web to exist, and do not want to upsert it. What I meant it that I want to upsert an **array item** with the the provided ip, if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just figured that out. And I tried doing everything I can. But I don't think it's possible with a single `findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera, ok, thank you